# How to set NSView Instance Properties

Tags: swift, nsview, appkit

In the [NSView class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview), there is a symbol [`canDraw`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview/1483277-candraw) that indicates whether drawing commands will produce any results.

The declaration is `var canDraw: Bool { get }` - so anytime you try something such as

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: NSView!
```

then `myView.canDraw = true`, you get a build-time error stating "`Cannot assign to property: 'canDraw' is a get-only property`". However, if I want to draw NSRect onto my view, how can I change this property?

Comment: You don't change it. Read the docs! It is reporting to you whether you have a context at this moment. If you want to take charge of drawing, you just implement the `draw` method. https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview/1483686-draw

Comment: @matt I tried implementing the `draw` method and saw no change whatsoever, so I had assumed that it was ignored due to the fact that `canDraw` was false. My Bad. I'll keep tinkering with `draw`.

Comment: OK, so you need to ask yourself _why_ `canDraw` is false. The docs say: "A view object can draw onscreen if it is not hidden, it is attached to a view hierarchy in a window (NSWindow), and the window has a corresponding window device." My guess is that your view object doesn't fulfill those criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change `canDraw` because it is read-only. It is read-only because it reports a matter of fact, over which you have no control, namely, whether this is a view you can draw into at this moment.

To draw into a view — that is, to implement an NSView that takes charge of drawing itself — subclass NSView and implement `draw`. Example:

[image]

The code shown in that screen shot is basically the only code in the application. The view in the window is a MyView, and MyView implements `draw`.